# Select multiple values with jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

my issue is finding all objects with a specific prefix in the classname, like in the following portion of html I'd like to be able to get us_mr and us_she with a single statement.

```
<div>
 <div class="us_me">Some about me</div>
 <div class="us_she">Some about she</div>
 <div class="they_she">Some about others</div>
</div>
```

this what I tried

```
$(".^us_")
```

assuming it would have found

```
<div class="us_me">Some about me</div>
<div class="us_she">Some about she</div>
```

but got syntax error

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try with `$("div[class^='us_']")`

### Working demo

```js
console.log($("div[class^='us_']").length);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="us_me">Some about me</div>
  <div class="us_she">Some about she</div>
  <div class="they_she">Some about others</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's great to hear! You're welcome :)

Comment: @DDS See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

Correct syntax for wildcard is: `[attribute^="value"]`.

Example:

```js
$("[class^='us_']").addClass('someClass');
```

```css
.someClass {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="us_me">Some about me</div>
  <div class="us_she">Some about she</div>
  <div class="they_she">Some about others</div>
</div>
```